# Flink state restore problems with value state of custom object

Tags: apache-flink

For Flink checkpoint restore from savepoint, it runs normally When we use value state of java basic type, but it throws Exception when using value state of java object which may be in-built or custom. What's the key solution for it? Any idea will be appreciated.

code like:

```
var playUVState: ValueState[BigInteger] = _
```

```
override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    playUVState = getRuntimeContext.getState(new ValueStateDescriptor[BigInteger]("playUVState", new BigIntSerializer()))
}
```

Exception when restoring from savepoint path:

```
java.lang.Exception: Exception while creating StreamOperatorStateContext.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:195)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:250)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:738)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:289)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:704)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not restore keyed state backend for LegacyKeyedProcessOperator_306d8342cb5b2ad8b53f1be57f65bee8_(28/32) from any of the 1 provided restore options.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:137)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.keyedStatedBackend(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:135)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend.readKeyGroupStateData(HeapKeyedStateBackend.java:479)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend.readStateHandleStateData(HeapKeyedStateBackend.java:453)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend.restorePartitionedState(HeapKeyedStateBackend.java:410)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend.restore(HeapKeyedStateBackend.java:358)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend.restore(HeapKeyedStateBackend.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.attemptCreateAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:151)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:123)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Is the new job running exactly the same code as the job that took the savepoint?

Comment: yes, code is same

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error you reported, using Flink 1.10 but was not able to. In general, the error you are seeing means that some key group was not found in the snapshot which could mean that either the file is corrupt, the TaskManager got the wrong file, or a serializer screwed things up. Since you are using the `BigIntSerializer`, this seems correct.

Judging from the stacktrace you provided, it looks like you are using Flink 1.7.2. Can you verify the same behaviour in Flink 1.10? If this still persists, I would be very much interested in getting a reproducible minimal (working) example which experiences this error.